# max-width not working on flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container and two flex children in a column. The top div should fill all remaining space. The bottom div should have a height determined by the content and a `max-width`. But the bottom div's width is shrinking to the width of its content. The `max-width` is being ignored.

```css
.hero_image {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.impact_image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/cjw1kzkkl/circles.png);
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro {
  max-width: 600px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: pink;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="impact_image"></div>
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>XYZ brand consultancy<br>making a difference</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cke6qr8e/

Comment: There is no problem in Safari (10.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [Michael_B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43705979/2827823), in this case it is the `margin: 0 auto` that cause the `.intro` to collapse, so if you remove it, its width will not collapse to its content, but that will also make the centering of it to not work as well.

Another solution would be to delete the `intro` rule and move its properties to the `h1` instead (all but `flex-shrink: 0`).

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

.hero_image {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.impact_image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/cjw1kzkkl/circles.png);
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro h1 {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="impact_image"></div>
  <div class="intro">
    <h1>XYZ brand consultancy<br>making a difference</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks that is cleaner code. Strange that it works without adding width:100% and resolves the margin: 0 auto; issue on the div.

Comment: @Markeee As Michael_B said, flexbox my vary in its behavior among browsers, and since it is a quite new standard, it will take some time before the browser manufacturer get it right in all variations one can use it.

Comment: @Markeee Also note, it might be in an upcoming update of `flexbox`, that one are _supposed_ to set a width, as in Michael_B's answer, so you need to keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 33):

Flex items, by default, may shrink to their content size. (This behavior may vary among browsers.)

This is because flex items no longer exist in a *block formatting context*, where block level elements automatically take `width: 100%`. In a *flex formatting context*, elements have different defaults.

Therefore, to get `max-width` to work on a flex item, also give the item `width: 100%`.

```css
.hero_image {
 min-height:100vh;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
  background-color:yellow;
 }

.impact_image {
 flex-grow:1;
 background-image:url(https://s16.postimg.org/cjw1kzkkl/circles.png);
 background-position: center bottom;
 background-size:cover;
 }
  
  .intro {
 max-width:600px;
 flex-shrink: 0;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-color:pink;
  width: 100%; /* NEW */
 }

h1 {
 font-size:20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
 <div class="impact_image"></div>
 <div class="intro"> 
  <h1>XYZ brand consultancy<br>making a difference</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was originally checking this problem in Safari (iPad), but couldn't see anything wrong. Once I moved to Chrome (PC) I saw what you were talking about.

Comment: How strange. Adding width:100% works on my Mac in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. I presume this works universally?

Comment: @Markeee Yes it does, for the exact reason Michael described

Comment: Thanks for the answer this solved my problem `max-width: 960px; width:100%;` tested in edge and chrome