# Max-width not working on Flexbox item (item is shrinking to width of content)

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a full viewport width, full viewport height "hero image" on a homepage. I've made this a Flex container. Inside the flex container is one child div (containing a heading). This flex item should be aligned to the bottom of the flex container. It has a max-width and should be horizontally centered inside the parent.

However, the max-width is being ignored. The div is taking the width of its content - the heading. Please see JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4h7q6d5x/

As you can see the .main div inside the hero image is taking the width of its content - unlike the .main div below the hero image.

I have looked at various questions, including this one [max-width not working on flex item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705866/max-width-not-working-on-flex-item)

But adding width:100% to the flex item doesn't work. At smaller viewport sizes the the width and padding don't play nicely and the heading is cropped off the right hand edge.

How do I get max-width to work with Flexbox?

```
.hero_image {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color:yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    }

.main {
    max-width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 50px;
    background-color:pink;
    }


<div class="hero_image">
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Heading <br>couple of words</h1>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="main">
    <p>Lots of content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking at the JS Fiddle on Firefox and Chrome on a Mac. The .main div inside the hero image is taking the width of the heading. The max-width is being ignored. It should be the same width as the .main div below it, that is outside the hero image.

Comment: It's fine, you specified a **max-width** property, but the block occupies less than that. If the block does not have enough content to reach that size, it will always be smaller. If you want the block to occupy those 500px, you must tell it to have `width: 500px`

Comment: @Artur Capraro I want it to have a max-width of 500px. Not a width of 500px. A max-width of 500px will have a width of 500px (if the viewport is big enough) even if its content is only 1px wide.

Comment: max-width works as @ArturCapraro  says

Comment: @Paulie_D It looks and works fine when the heading / content is long enough to push the div to the max-width. But the heading is only 4 words long and the max-width is being ignored. Try your JS Fiddle with only 4 words and you'll be able to see

Comment: @Sfili_81  Have a look at my JS Fiddle and the .main div underneather / outside the hero image. It has a max width of 500px , but its content is much less. Or are you saying that max-width works differently when used with FlexBox?

Comment: _The max-width CSS property sets the maximum width of an element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified by max-width._

Comment: @Paulie_D  If you have a look at my JS Fiddle, you'll see that the .main div underneath the hero image has a max-width of 500px even though its content is not very wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default "width" (actually `flex-basis`) inside flex-containers  is `auto` which makes it only as wide as it's content.

> But adding width:100% to the flex item doesn't work. At smaller viewport sizes the the width and padding don't play nicely and the heading is cropped off the right hand edge.

Then I'd suggest a couple of changes. Don't use a flex-column but position your `.main` div using `align-items:flex-end`.

Then set the default "width" (actually flex-grow) with `flex: 1`.

```css
.hero_image {
  min-height: 50vh;
  /* for example */
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  /* for example */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Heading <br>couple of words</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p>Lots of text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this working? Is flex:1 saying that the flex item should grow as large as it can until it gets to the max-width? Or should I be using flex-basis to set the initial length of the item? "The flex-basis property specifies the initial length of a flex item" And remove the max-width from the .main div inside the hero image?